# How to plot values in a matrix

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

suppose I have a matrix like this:

```
          trainingSize trainingTime accuracy
 [1,]         1179        0.923    0.262
 [2,]         2356        0.953    0.563
 [3,]         3536        0.971    0.869
 [4,]         4712        0.979    1.212
 [5,]         5889        0.983    1.542
```

How can I plot trainingSize VS accuracy and trainingTime VS accuracy in a 2 dimensional space?

```
qplot(lcMatrix[,1], lcMatrix[,3])
qplot(lcMatrix[,2], lcMatrix[,3])
```

These two commands will plot separately. How to plot them together?

Does this work?

```
qplot(lcMatrix[,1], lcMatrix[,3]) + qplot(lcMatrix[,2], lcMatrix[,3])
```

Comment: I would use something like `ggplot(melt(as.data.frame(m), id="accuracy"), aes(x = accuracy, y = value, color  = variable)) + geom_point()` although that would convert the matrix to a data.frame inside the `ggplot` command, so I'm not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: Almost. On top of it, can it add another plot trainingSize VS trainingTime?

Comment: I'm afraid someone else will have to help you with that one.

Comment: This wasn't the original question. you can't just add new questions when you have your previous once answered. What about plotting a car image on top of everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting from comment ..

Here's a way to plot trainingSize VS accuracy and trainingTime VS accuracy in one plot:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

ggplot(melt(as.data.frame(m), id="accuracy"), 
        aes(x = accuracy, y = value, color = variable)) + 
        geom_point()
```

So I would convert the matrix to a data.frame and melt the resulting data.frame with `id = "accuracy"` afterwards it can easily be plotted in one plot.

Comment: What is color=variable? and y=value? should x=accuracy be x="accuracy"? I copied the command and it won't work.

Comment: Did you install and load the package `reshape2`? When you `melt` the data.frame, the molten columns get new names which are `variable` and `value`. In my answer I assume that your matrix is called `m`. You can check that out by running `melt(as.data.frame(m), id="accuracy")`.

Comment: Welcome. FYI `color=variable` ensures that you get different colors for points of trainingSize and trainingTime. It also adds a legend to the plot explaining the colors. You can check what's happening if you remove that bit.